# Google Auth Error - com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, youtube, google-play-services

I'm studying Android programming and I'm having an error. It says:

> "com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException:
>   NeedPermission"

Code

https://pastebin.com/kZivbfCm

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Error

> Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException:
>   NeedPermission

I googled for whole day but not solved yet.

I'm using Youtube API and I have error for it.

Please help me.

Yes, added to Google API page.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/16PnR.png
And also YouTube API has ENABLED.

++ADDED

```
Class

    private Context context1;

    public YouTubePlaylistsLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context1 = context;
    }
```

and I tried

```
 context1.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
```

But It says cannot resolve that function.
I pressed Ctrl + SPACE and It only shows "startActivity(intent)"

Comment: Please include your code and the full text of the error.

Comment: Did you add api in developer console?

Comment: I added and finger print added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code where

```
        // I catched but I don't know how to handle.
        // I tried startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION); this but it gives me red line.
        // It says "Cannot resolve method startActivityForResult"
        // And also "Cannot resolve symbol REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION"
```

You need activity context to start activity for result. `context.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);`
Take a look [in here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: I tried but It says "Cannot resolve symbol 'context' ". Do I have to declare new one?

Comment: You have to add `Context contex` to the class constructor

Comment: I added on my post. Check please. thanks for answer. help me

Comment: use like that `((Activity)context)startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);`

Comment: Oh.. This worked perfectly. I love you so much. You're my savior. Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!! voted and checked. Thank you!!!